# How to fix memory leak in scipy.stats when generating random variates with rv_continuous?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scipy

The following minimal example appears to suffer from memory leak (tested using SciPy verison 0.17.0)

```
import resource
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

class Rv(rv_continuous):

    def __init__(self, x):
        rv_continuous.__init__(self, a=0, b=1)
        self.x = x

    def _pdf(self, y):
        return 1


def call_rv(x):
    rv = Rv(x)
    # if the line below is commented out, memory usage stays constant
    s = rv.rvs()

    return 1

for k in range(10000):
    x = call_rv(k)
    if k%1000==0:
        mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
        print 'Memory usage: %s (kb)' % mem
```

I don't understand what causes the leak in my example. Notably, when the random variate generation `s = rv.rvs()` is commented out, the leak doesn't occur.

How can the memory leak be avoided when using `rv_continuous` and random variate generation?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a memory leak, the memory is going to be returned to the OS, eventually.

```
rv = Rv(x)
```

creates a new instance in the loop.  Don't do that, and your memory consumption will be in check.
If you want to generate N variates, create the instance once and then do `.rvs(size=N)`.

Comment: Can you explain more why it is not a memory leak? The process does consume more and more memory with time. Also, the line of code you reference seems fine, as long as I don't call rv.rvs() afterwards. Thank you in any case though, your comment got me to rethink the structure of my code and I was able to come up with a solution that doesn't require the creation of new instances in the loop.

Comment: You can call garbage collection in the loop to check whether it's just delayed garbage collection.

Comment: Check with your OS system monitor. A memory leak means memory consumption does not go down after you quit the Python process.

Comment: I had the same issue. By that definition it isnt a memory leak, but it is a brutal memory consumption that is not fixed by garbage collector (reference cycle possibly?). I need to create a few thousand random variables from which I only need one random sample. Got my python code to use up to 20G for 4000 simulations. It limits how many simulations I can do in one go. Solutions I've found range from using workers with few tasks (multiprocessing) or writing a function that returns random samples by solving numerically the inverse of the cdf myself. Still, it appears it is a scipy.stats bug, no?

Comment: The Rv class object rv should be local to call_rv and be destroyed each time you return from that function to the main code. Even calling "del rv" and "gc.collect()" fails to destroy the Rv class objects...

Comment: Re immediate garbage collection: This is not how python works. Re several thousand frozen random variables to sample only once from each: this is not an optimal use of scipy.stats.distributions. COnsider asking a separate question about that