# How to keep memory consumption at bay when using scipy.stats.rv_continuous?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` (v0.19.0) in order to create random values from a custom probability distribution. The code I am using looks as follows (using a Gaussian for debugging purposes):

```
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
import numpy as np
import resource
import scipy
import sys

print "numpy version: {}".format(np.version.full_version)
print "Scipy version: {}".format(scipy.version.full_version)
print "Python {}".format(sys.version)

class gaussian_gen(rv_continuous):
    "Gaussian distribution"
    def _pdf(self, x):
        return np.exp(-x**2 / 2.) / np.sqrt(2.0 * np.pi)

def print_mem():
    mem = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    print 'Memory usage: %s (kb)' % mem

print_mem()
gaussian = gaussian_gen(name='gaussian')
print_mem()
values = gaussian.rvs(size=1000)
print_mem()
values = gaussian.rvs(size=5000)
print_mem()
```

Which outputs:

```
numpy version: 1.12.0
Scipy version: 0.19.0
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Memory usage: 69672 (kb)
Memory usage: 69672 (kb)
Memory usage: 426952 (kb)
Memory usage: 2215576 (kb)
```

As you can see, the memory consumption of this snippet seems really unreasonable. I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075272/how-to-fix-memory-leak-in-scipy-stats-when-generating-random-variates-with-rv-co), but it is slightly different since I am not creating a new class instance in a loop.

I thought that I am using rv_continuous correctly, but I cannot see why it would consume such enormous amounts of memory. How do I use it correctly? Ideally, I would like to have a solution which I can actually be call in a loop, but one step at a time.

Comment: On my PC, your code snippet does not change RAM consumption at all but takes about 1 minute to execute.

Comment: Are calling it inside a loop ? how many times ?  Are you sure, that you do not accidentally create many many instances of that class ?

Comment: I added more details to the snippet. It now prints the given output in a newly started jupyter-notebook kernel. Talking of newly started: The memory is freed once the kernel is restarted, but `del gaussian` for example does not do the trick.

Comment: This is either a bug or a python 2 issue. On python3 (anaconda), memory usage does not change at all

Comment: I just opened an issue about this, and also realized that it seems to work again for the latest master: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7253 Thanks for all the comments!